# Cant Choose USB Boot From BIOS/UEFI

Tags: boot, usb, bios, usb-flash-drive, uefi

I have Philips 32 GB flashdisc. (FM32FD75B/97) When i enter boot options, i cannot see my device. I tried it with 1 desktop and 2 laptops and result is same.

I also used Rufus/Unetbootin and Ubuntu internal Startup Disc Creator to make bootable disc with Ubuntu iso. When i used another USB memory with Rufus and this ISO it started flawlessly.

Briefly i have a problem with my USB Flashdrive and how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The OS that you copied to your USB Flashdrive must support UEFI boot (if it supports, it will have an EFI folder in the root directory of your USB Flashdrive).. else your USB Flashdrive won't be shown

Comment: Yeah there is EFI folder in the root directory. I use different USB Flashdrive with same options and other Flashdrive boots well.

Comment: in which format is your USB device formated??

Comment: I formetted my USB with both NTFS and FAT32. Actually i used every option in Rufus. I tried GPT or MBR partition too.

Comment: it was reported that some usb devices wont boot.. Why dont you try it in CSM/Legacy boot?